# Having trouble increasing spacing between horizontal menu items with CSS

Tags: html, css, menu, margin

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
li {
    display:inline;
    padding: 10px;
}
#menu {
    margin: 21px 646px 21px 646px;
}
```

I cannot seem to increase the space between the menu items.  What should I adjust to do so?

Comment: Use `inline-block` instead of `inline`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try

```
a { 
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

---

edit

Do you want something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Ng7/

Just remove that ridiculous margin you have for the nav and increase the li padding

```
li {
    display:inline;
    padding: 10px 40px;
}
```

To center a div element, don't do `margin: 21px 646px 21px 646px;`

just do `margin: 21px auto;`

Comment: I have tried the `margin: 21px auto;` but this pushed the menu to the left.  How can I center the menu items in a responsive fashion?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `display:inline-block;` in list menu.

Change your `CSS` like below :

```
li {
   display:inline-block;
   padding: 10px;
}

#menu {
    margin: 21px 646px 21px 646px;
}
```

Or See [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ee2aaxc0/)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to manipulate the list items, try adding your padding to the anchor. Ex:

```
#menu li a { padding: 10px; display: block; }
```